# R: Having trouble producing multiple multi-number samples

Tags: r, random, sample

I'm trying to draw samples from a `runif(100,900,1100)` population. Now I want to draw 25 samples of size n = 5 from this population with replacement, but it seems that `sample()` outputs only scalar samples. What is the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a `5*25` matrix (each column corresponds to one sample) with numbers generated from a uniform distribution.

```
matrix(runif(5*25,900,1100), nrow = 5, ncol = 25)
```

or you can do the following if instead, you want to first generate `runif(100,900,1100)`, then draw 25 samples from the resulting vector:

```
sapply(1:25, function(x) sample(runif(100,900,1100), 5, replace = TRUE))
```